# Recursion and Catalan Numbers

Tags: catalan-numbers

> Consider the sequence defined by
>   $$
> \begin{cases}
> r_0=1\\
> r_1=3\\
> r_n=6r_{n-1}-9r_{n-2} & \text{if }n\ge 2
> \end{cases}
> .$$
>   Find a closed form for $r_n$.
>
> Your response should be a formula in terms of $n$, and should not contain terms such as $r_n,$ $r_{n-1},$ and so on. Do not include $``r_n=\text{''}$ in your response.

I realize that the characteristic equation of the recurrence is $c^2-6c+9$ and that can be factored into $(c-3)(c-3)$. So, I then have $$r_{0} = \lambda_1+\lambda_2$$ and $$r_1 = 3\lambda_1+3\lambda_2.$$ But shouldn't this have infinite solutions?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. This is a [constant-recursive sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-recursive_sequence) in which the characteristic polynomial has a *double root* equal to $3$. In this case, the general term has the form $c_n = (\lambda_1 + n \lambda_2)3^n$.